# How to update the height of ion-searchbar in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to develop a search functionality in Ionic 4 with `<ion-searchbar>`. The problem I have is with the height of the search bar, I can't manipulate it. I know Ionic 4 is web component based and it wraps every component inside a shadow DOM but `<ion-searchbar>` doesn't seem to have a shadow DOM as can be seen below:

[image]

Unlike other components where shadow DOM is visible within the nodes like this one:

[image]

This makes me think that I can override the `div` with class `searchbar-input-container` within the `<ion-searchbar>` but I can't and even Ionic official documentation doesn't cover any property or variable with which this can be attained. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much of trouble, I tried with a solution which can be considered as a workaround too by some people. I used `transform: scale` of CSS to scale my `<ion-searchbar>`. So the code now becomes:

```
ion-searchbar {        
    transform: scale(1.2); // Can also scale individually with scaleX() and scaleY()
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%; // To avoid pixelate effect that occurs with scaling
}
```

You can also use `zoom` CSS property as `zoom: 1.2` but as per MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom), it is recommended to use **transform** over **zoom**.

This allows us to increase the height without accessing the `div` with class `searchbar-input-container`.

Answer (score 0):

This was tricky but finally I found a solution that is pretty simple.

Basically find the class that affects the `<input>` tag inside the `ion-searchbar`.
Look at the CSS properties that are being applied, pick up the whole class name verbatim as it is, and use this in your global.scss file.

In my case it was:

```
.searchbar-left-aligned.sc-ion-searchbar-ios-h .searchbar-input.sc-ion-searchbar-ios
{ 
     // whatever styles i want to increase the size... 
}
```